# Powershell Script to show what SSAS databases have not been processed in the last 24 hours

Tags: sql, powershell, ssas

I've been trying to create a script to create a list of SSAS cubes that have not been processed in the last 24 hours, but I'm not having much luck. I've got a query that will give me the process time of a specific cube, but it only works on the specific database that is selected to query against. I'm needing it to list this information for all databases on a SSAS server.

The query that I'm using is:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[LastProcessed] AS ASSP.GetCubeLastProcessedDate()
SELECT      [Measures].[LastProcessed] ON 0 FROM $Database"
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. If this is possible to do with just T-SQL or MDX instead of Powershell, that would be fine as well, but I have not been able to locate a command in SQL to pull in all of the cube names.

Also, this is running on Microsoft SQL Server 2012 if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your script:

```
USE $Database;
GO

WITH MEMBER [Measures].[LastProcessed] AS ASSP.GetCubeLastProcessedDate()
SELECT      [Measures].[LastProcessed] ON 0 FROM $Database"
```

If you're running the [Invoke-SqlCmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx) cmdlet with the -Database option the query will connect to the specified database.  The `USE $Database` statement should force the connection to switch to the appropriate database context before executing.